# Centroid of unsymetric bending in T-section

Tags: structural-engineering, beam

[image]

Can anyone please explain how this 24 is coming while calculating the x-cordinate of the centroid.

Comment: 120/2-40+4. X is measured from the side of one wall 40 is measured to center and a half wall is 4

Answer (score 0):

That describes the distance from the arbitrary origin to the upper section's x-centroid.

The upper section is a rectangle with a 120 mm base. Therefore, we know the centroid is at the center of the base (60 mm from either the left or right face of that section.

However, for some weird reason, the question defines the origin on the left face of the bottom section. So how far is the upper section's centroid?

$$\dfrac{40 + 80}{2} - 40 + \dfrac{8}{2} = 2\text{ mm}$$